# ionic 2 como adicionar Authorization no header

Tags: javascript, ionic2

Faz dias que estou tentando e não consigo com o seguinte método no *ionic 2*.

```
getMy() {
    return this.http.get("users/my", this.setAuthorization(this.headers))
                    .toPromise()
                    .then(res => res.json())
                    .catch(this.handleError);
}

protected setAuthorization(headers) {
    headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"));
    return {headers: headers};
}
```

Na minha *request* simplesmente não esta sendo enviado o meu *token* de autorização:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Edit 1**
Damon Dudek decidi fazer de outra forma como estou com o ionic 2 versão que utilizar o angular 4.1.3, ou seja não possui os interceptors ainda implementei o meu proprio por enquanto e esta assim

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, ConnectionBackend, Headers, RequestOptions, Request, 
RequestOptionsArgs } from '@angular/http';

@Injectable()
export class BaseProvider extends Http {

  private headers: Headers = new Headers();
  private urlApi: string = "*********";

  constructor(backend?: ConnectionBackend, defaultOptions?: RequestOptions) 
  {
    super(backend, defaultOptions);
    this.headers.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; 
    charset=UTF-8");
  }

  request(request: Request, options?: RequestOptionsArgs) {
   if(localStorage.hasOwnProperty("token")) {
     this.headers.append("Authorization", "Bearer " + 
     localStorage.getItem("token"));
   }
   request.url = this.urlApi + request.url;
   request.headers = this.headers;
   return super.request(request, options);
   }
}
```

perceba como ficou minha request no log do chrome
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

ai a request passa só que como OPTIONS e me retorna problema de CORS sendo que está 100% habilitado no meu servidor

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load *********. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8100' is therefore not allowed access.
```

só que eu percebi uma coisa quando faço a request no postman como OPTIONS não me retorna nada já como GET me retorna algo, acho que o problema esta no fato do angular esta forçando minha request a ser OPTIONS. Alguem se habilita a me ajudar?

Answer (score 0):

Faz da seguinte maneira.
Defina o teu header antes do teu request:

```
let headers = new Headers();
headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer token');
```

Faça a chamada passando o header como o objeto, igual você fez:

```
{ headers: headers }
```

Isto funciona, é assim que eu utilizo as minhas requisições no angular2.

Abaixo um trecho de um chamada completa que eu utilizo como referência.

```
getCard(idBeneficiario) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        this.storage.get('token').then((value) => {

            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Authorization', value);

            this.http.get(AppConfig.apiEndpoint + '/DadosAdicionais?idBeneficiario=' + idBeneficiario, { headers: headers })
                .subscribe(res => {

                    let data = res.json();

                    resolve(data);
                }, (err) => {
                    reject(err);
                });
        });

    });
}
```

**Lembrando:**
Você precisa fazer os imports e definir no seu construtor conforme abaixo:

```
import { Http, Headers } from '@angular/http';

constructor(public http: Http) { }
```